# How can I list exported values from all of my CloudFormation templates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm exporting the name of the stack and the URL of my Lambda function in my CloudFormation template.

```yaml
Outputs:
  LambdaInvokeURL:
    Value: !GetAtt Myurl.FunctionUrl 
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}"
```

I have 8 to 10 stacks exporting similar outputs.

How can I list all exported names & values across all stacks in my AWS account?

Should I write a new CloudFormation template or a Lambda function to list them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `aws cloudformation list-exports` [CLI command](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/list-exports.html), the `ListExports` [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_ListExports.html) or any of the [equivalent SDK methods](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_ListExports.html#API_ListExports_SeeAlso).

You don’t need to write a new CloudFormation template or a Lambda function for this.

Sample output as per docs:

```json
{
    "Exports": [
        {
            "ExportingStackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:123456789012:stack/private-vpc/99764070-b56c-xmpl-bee8-062a88d1d800",
            "Name": "private-vpc-subnet-a",
            "Value": "subnet-07b410xmplddcfa03"
        },
        {
            "ExportingStackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:123456789012:stack/private-vpc/99764070-b56c-xmpl-bee8-062a88d1d800",
            "Name": "private-vpc-subnet-b",
            "Value": "subnet-075ed3xmplebd2fb1"
        },
        {
            "ExportingStackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:123456789012:stack/private-vpc/99764070-b56c-xmpl-bee8-062a88d1d800",
            "Name": "private-vpc-vpcid",
            "Value": "vpc-011d7xmpl100e9841"
        }
    ]
}
```